# Encoding spring ldap server manager password

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

We just upgraded out app to spring 5. I'm using an ldap server and I wanted to know if I can encode the manager-password.

```
<ldap-server id="contextSource" url="ldap://n.n.n.n" manager-dn="myuser" manager-password="cleartextpassword"/>
```

The spring security encoding I've read is in regard to the authentication manager.. This would be more similar to encoding them in a properties file. I haven't found anything withing BCrypt that may do this for me..

My current option that I can think of would be to 
1. Use bcrypt to encode the password and then extend the LdapSourceContext and decrypt it there.
2. add Jasypt to do the encryption/decryption

If there is anything in Spring 5 that I missed let me know.

I was just wondering if I had missed anything already in spring that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using Jasypt. Everything I found with spring5 and Boot point to Jasypt.. It is simple to use..